# paste function in ggtitle: remove extra spaces and add a new line in ggplot title

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggtitle

Within the shiny context, how can I remove extra space after and before parentheses in the title of a plot? As shown in the below image, there are redundant spaces between "(" and "6" as well as between "+" and ")".

Also, I was wondering how can I break down the title in such a way that the county name as well as the age group appear in the next line.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
ggtitle(
    paste(
      "Percentage of Population Living with and Responsible for Grandchildren in", 
      input$county_grandpa,
      "(",
      input$Age_Group_grandpa,
     ")"
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: use `paste0` instead of `paste`. You need to add a space after ***... Grandchildren in "***!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job for you. `paste0` doesn't have `sep = " "` like `paste` and `\n` adds a new line. Add `theme` if you want the text to be centered.

```
ggtitle(
    paste0(
      "Percentage of Population Living with and Responsible for Grandchildren in \n",
      input$county_grandpa,
      " (",
      input$Age_Group_grandpa,
     ")"
    ) 
  ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```